# Flip page javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola sou novo por aqui e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida (não sou programador profissional) Tem como eu fazer feito flip page que ao invés de carregar imagens ou PDF, ele carregar uma pagina html. Baixei o http://www.turnjs.com/# mas, fiquei perdido, se alguém pudesse me dar uma força eu ficaria feliz.

```
/*
 * Basic sample
*/

function addPage(page, book) {

    var id, pages = book.turn('pages');

    // Create a new element for this page
    var element = $('<div />', {});

    // Add the page to the flipbook
    if (book.turn('addPage', element, page)) {

        // Add the initial HTML
        // It will contain a loader indicator and a gradient
        element.html('<div class="gradient"></div><div class="loader"></div>');

        // Load the page
        loadPage(page, element);
    }

}

function loadPage(page, pageElement) {

    // Create an image element

    var img = $('<img />');

    img.mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    img.load(function() {

        // Set the size
        $(this).css({width: '100%', height: '100%'});

        // Add the image to the page after loaded

        $(this).appendTo(pageElement);

        // Remove the loader indicator

        pageElement.find('.loader').remove();
    });

    // Load the page

    img.attr('src', 'pages/' +  page + '.jpg');

}


function loadLargePage(page, pageElement) {

    var img = $('<img />');

    img.load(function() {

        var prevImg = pageElement.find('img');
        $(this).css({width: '100%', height: '100%'});
        $(this).appendTo(pageElement);
        prevImg.remove();

    });

    // Loadnew page

    img.attr('src', 'pages/' +  page + '-large.jpg');
}


function loadSmallPage(page, pageElement) {

    var img = pageElement.find('img');

    img.css({width: '100%', height: '100%'});

    img.unbind('load');
    // Loadnew page

    img.attr('src', 'pages/' +  page + '.jpg');
}



// http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128488
function isChrome() {

    return navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')!=-1;

}
```